# Get a summary table with basic statistics for several variables at the same time

Tags: r, statistics

I have a file with 30 variables and 2000 individual. But a summary would be something like as:

```
  Name Farm milk protein fat dim data 
  1110 PE   10.3  3,7    3.6 146 06/07/20
  3322 PE   18.3  3,3    3.9 158 06/03/20 
  1125 PE   22.3  3,4  4.6 210 12/04/20 
  1777 PE   14.3  3,0    4.2 100 28/04/20
  8970 PE   17.3  3,2    3.6 185 14/06/20
```

I need:

1. Calculate for all the variables mean, median, min, max, quartiles and **group all the results into a unique/single table**, I used three options:

```
sapply (fenotipi2, summary) R ##print only two columns with all values ​​together
```

```r
library(purrr) 
library(dplyr)

phenotype2 %>% 
    map (~ summary (.)) %>%
    rbind.data.frame 
## Error in rbind.data.frame(.): 
##       invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
```

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
phenotype2 %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    summarize_at(vars (value), list(Min = min, Mean = mean, 
                                    Max = max, Sd = sd))  
## A tibble: 1 x 4
## Min Mean Max Sd   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 1 NA NA NA NA
```

2. I must also do all the histograms and distributions for continuous variables in one step, I used

```r
require(MVN)
    
result = mvn(data = fenotipi2 [-4], subset = "Species", mvnTest = "hz",
                 univariateTest = "AD", univariatePlot = "histogram",
                 multivariatePlot = "qq", multivariateOutlierMethod = "adj",
                 showOutliers = TRUE, showNewData = TRUE)
```

I don't get the desired results.

Comment: `summary` output depends on the class of the column.  In the code, there are two datasets `phenotype2` and `fenotipi2`.  which one of them is the data showed

Comment: I am sorry, fenotipi2 = phenotype2..is the same file

Comment: There are some packages for dealing with exploratory data stuff.  You may use `Hmisc::describe(fenotipi2)`

Comment: I find `dfSummary` from [`summarytools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Introduction.html) package very useful for quick exploration of many variables

Comment: @akrun thank you so much....Do you know if it is possible to print the results in an excel file? or similar

Comment: @JohannaRamirez I understand that the results are not exactly in a correct tabular format.  One option if you want to keep it as such is `capture.output(Hmisc::describe(fenotipi2), file = "yourfile.txt")`

Comment: @akrun thank you again....capture.output(Hmisc::describe(fenotipi2), file = "yourfile.txt") .. it was very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `describe` from `Hmisc` and then write it to a file with `capture.output`

```
capture.output(Hmisc::describe(fenotipi2), file = "yourfile.txt")
```